# Are D3 value keys matched in the same way that default index numbers are when using enter()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm running through some D3.js code ([a great explanation of keys, by index and by value](http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.ca/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html)), and came to a question about using value as the key. In the following code snippet, I'm using the index as the key in the selection.data() function:

```
<body>
     <div id="example2">
        <p>Already existing paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Already existing paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     pdata = [10,12,6,8,15];

     selectDIV = d3.select("#example2");

    selectDIV.selectAll("p")
         .data(pdata)
         .enter()
         .append("p")
         .text(function(d){return d;});
 </script>
 </body>
```

The output, then, will be

> Already existing paragraph 1
>
> Already existing paragraph 2
>
> 6
>
> 8
>
> 15

This makes sense, since we've already got 2 `<p>` elements in the extant array, and because we're using the element index as the key, only the elements with index numbers other than those already present will be added.

In order to get a sense of how keys work, I tried out a key function that uses element values, rather than element index numbers:

```
<body>
     <div id="example3">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>Already existing paragraph 2</p>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         pdata = [1,"Already existing paragraph 2",6,8,15,15];

         selectDIV = d3.select("#example3");

        selectDIV.selectAll("p")
             .data(pdata, function(d){return d;})
             .enter()
             .append("p")
             .text(function(d){return d;});
     </script>
 </body>
```

The output, in this case, happens to be

> 1
>
> Already existing paragraph 2
>
> 1
>
> Already existing paragraph 2
>
> 6
>
> 8
>
> 15
>
> 15

So, if I'm using the value as keys, why is it that if values in the `<p>` tags match the `<p>` tag values in the array I've specified, the values are written twice? I would've thought that the presence of the string "Already existing paragraph 2" in both the already-created array of `<p>` tags would have meant that any elements with the same value wouldn't recur?

Or, is this actually the case, and am I just too much of a JS n00b to realize that D3 perceives them as different values?

If it's merely a case of matching array index numbers to filter the enter() selection, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out when there would be an overlap when using the value as the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example you're using the data bound to the element as the key (`d`), *not* the text value assigned to it -- the two just happen to be the same. No data is bound to the existing two elements, so nothing is matched and everything ends up in the `enter()` selection.

To achieve the effect you're looking for, you need to "bind" the data to the existing elements before executing the code:

```
d3.selectAll("p").each(function() { this.__data__ = d3.select(this).text(); })
```